# aiortc can't receive video from server example

Tags: python, webrtc, p2p, aiortc

I am trying to run the [server aiortc example](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/tree/main/examples/server) but i cannot receive video.

The logs are:

```
C:\Users\cpapp\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\aiortc-main\examples\server>python server.py
======== Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 ========
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:pc:PeerConnection(77b8cd03-e51e-4425-8eca-4b6486a853de) Created for 127.0.0.1
INFO:pc:PeerConnection(77b8cd03-e51e-4425-8eca-4b6486a853de) Track audio received
INFO:pc:PeerConnection(77b8cd03-e51e-4425-8eca-4b6486a853de) Track video received
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(3) Could not bind to 169.254.119.55 - [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(3) Could not bind to 169.254.248.136 - [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Could not bind to 169.254.119.55 - [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Could not bind to 169.254.248.136 - [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(4) Could not bind to 169.254.119.55 - [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(4) Could not bind to 169.254.248.136 - [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(3) Could not bind to 169.254.144.162 - [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Could not bind to 169.254.144.162 - [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(4) Could not bind to 169.254.144.162 - [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52', 62599) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52', 64963)) State.FROZEN -> State.WAITING
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b95:1600:31ba:5d7a:57f6:a649', 62602) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52', 64963)) State.FROZEN -> State.WAITING
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b95:1600:99ef:ddf0:c156:571b', 62605) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52', 64963)) State.FROZEN -> State.WAITING
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1', 62608) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52', 64963)) State.FROZEN -> State.WAITING
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52', 62599) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1', 64964)) State.FROZEN -> State.WAITING
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('192.168.1.188', 62611) -> ('192.168.1.188', 64962)) State.FROZEN -> State.WAITING
INFO:pc:PeerConnection(77b8cd03-e51e-4425-8eca-4b6486a853de) Connection state is connecting
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52', 62599) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52', 64963)) State.WAITING -> State.IN_PROGRESS
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b95:1600:31ba:5d7a:57f6:a649', 62602) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52', 64963)) State.WAITING -> State.IN_PROGRESS
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b95:1600:99ef:ddf0:c156:571b', 62605) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52', 64963)) State.WAITING -> State.IN_PROGRESS
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1', 62608) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52', 64963)) State.WAITING -> State.IN_PROGRESS
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52', 62599) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1', 64964)) State.WAITING -> State.IN_PROGRESS
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('192.168.1.188', 62611) -> ('192.168.1.188', 64962)) State.WAITING -> State.IN_PROGRESS
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('192.168.1.188', 62611) -> ('192.168.1.188', 64962)) State.IN_PROGRESS -> State.SUCCEEDED
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b95:1600:31ba:5d7a:57f6:a649', 62602) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1', 64964)) State.FROZEN -> State.FAILED
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b95:1600:99ef:ddf0:c156:571b', 62605) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1', 64964)) State.FROZEN -> State.FAILED
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1', 62608) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1', 64964)) State.FROZEN -> State.FAILED
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) ICE completed
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b95:1600:31ba:5d7a:57f6:a649', 62602) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1', 64964)) State.FAILED -> State.IN_PROGRESS
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b95:1600:99ef:ddf0:c156:571b', 62605) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1', 64964)) State.FAILED -> State.IN_PROGRESS
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1', 62608) -> ('2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1', 64964)) State.FAILED -> State.IN_PROGRESS
```

in the html page the ice connection states are:

```
ICE gathering state: new -> gathering -> complete

ICE connection state: new -> checking -> connected

Signaling state: stable -> have-local-offer -> stable
```

The Media section is empty.
The Datachannel section has ping pong messages.
The sdp offer is:

```
v=0
o=- 2836547731808777488 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS eac6381c-162d-49b9-8627-b13e89dfd104
m=audio 64962 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 63 9 0 8 13 110 126
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.188
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:3748716806 1 udp 2122129151 192.168.1.188 64962 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
a=candidate:2755392946 1 udp 2122262783 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52 64963 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=candidate:4069116403 1 udp 2122197247 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1 64964 typ host generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
a=candidate:567948690 1 tcp 1518149375 192.168.1.188 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
a=candidate:1519460646 1 tcp 1518283007 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=candidate:203627879 1 tcp 1518217471 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
a=ice-ufrag:hB4s
a=ice-pwd:dUGYmKslWIuGp2oMexX8hewx
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 9F:5C:6B:F4:49:E7:1D:FF:A6:94:AE:5C:A4:8F:24:27:2D:C3:BB:BF:97:25:98:0B:6A:FB:90:E8:58:05:10:A7
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=sendrecv
a=msid:eac6381c-162d-49b9-8627-b13e89dfd104 f199f771-9469-44dc-a4ec-cf50b5e77195
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:63 red/48000/2
a=fmtp:63 111/111
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:4194854398 cname:w8/dPGydR3sbOAcN
a=ssrc:4194854398 msid:eac6381c-162d-49b9-8627-b13e89dfd104 f199f771-9469-44dc-a4ec-cf50b5e77195
m=video 64965 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 127 125 39 40 45 46 98 99 100 101 112 113 116 117 118
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.188
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:3748716806 1 udp 2122129151 192.168.1.188 64965 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
a=candidate:2755392946 1 udp 2122262783 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52 64966 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=candidate:4069116403 1 udp 2122197247 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1 64967 typ host generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
a=candidate:567948690 1 tcp 1518149375 192.168.1.188 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
a=candidate:1519460646 1 tcp 1518283007 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=candidate:203627879 1 tcp 1518217471 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
a=ice-ufrag:hB4s
a=ice-pwd:dUGYmKslWIuGp2oMexX8hewx
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 9F:5C:6B:F4:49:E7:1D:FF:A6:94:AE:5C:A4:8F:24:27:2D:C3:BB:BF:97:25:98:0B:6A:FB:90:E8:58:05:10:A7
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:1
a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:10 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:11 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=sendrecv
a=msid:eac6381c-162d-49b9-8627-b13e89dfd104 9b0b3aad-e921-4779-aa97-7a3602d7c2ae
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:103 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:103 apt=102
a=rtpmap:104 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:104 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:104 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:104 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:104 nack
a=rtcp-fb:104 nack pli
a=fmtp:104 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:105 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:105 apt=104
a=rtpmap:106 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:106 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:106 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:106 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:106 nack
a=rtcp-fb:106 nack pli
a=fmtp:106 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=106
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d001f
a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:125 apt=127
a=rtpmap:39 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:39 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:39 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:39 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:39 nack
a=rtcp-fb:39 nack pli
a=fmtp:39 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=4d001f
a=rtpmap:40 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:40 apt=39
a=rtpmap:45 AV1/90000
a=rtcp-fb:45 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:45 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:45 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:45 nack
a=rtcp-fb:45 nack pli
a=rtpmap:46 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:46 apt=45
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 profile-id=2
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:112 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:112 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:112 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:112 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:112 nack
a=rtcp-fb:112 nack pli
a=fmtp:112 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64001f
a=rtpmap:113 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:113 apt=112
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:117 apt=116
a=rtpmap:118 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 2549948813 3656120440
a=ssrc:2549948813 cname:w8/dPGydR3sbOAcN
a=ssrc:2549948813 msid:eac6381c-162d-49b9-8627-b13e89dfd104 9b0b3aad-e921-4779-aa97-7a3602d7c2ae
a=ssrc:3656120440 cname:w8/dPGydR3sbOAcN
a=ssrc:3656120440 msid:eac6381c-162d-49b9-8627-b13e89dfd104 9b0b3aad-e921-4779-aa97-7a3602d7c2ae
m=application 64968 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.188
a=candidate:3748716806 1 udp 2122129151 192.168.1.188 64968 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
a=candidate:2755392946 1 udp 2122262783 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52 64969 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=candidate:4069116403 1 udp 2122197247 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1 64970 typ host generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
a=candidate:567948690 1 tcp 1518149375 192.168.1.188 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
a=candidate:1519460646 1 tcp 1518283007 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=candidate:203627879 1 tcp 1518217471 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
a=ice-ufrag:hB4s
a=ice-pwd:dUGYmKslWIuGp2oMexX8hewx
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 9F:5C:6B:F4:49:E7:1D:FF:A6:94:AE:5C:A4:8F:24:27:2D:C3:BB:BF:97:25:98:0B:6A:FB:90:E8:58:05:10:A7
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:2
a=sctp-port:5000
a=max-message-size:262144
```

and the sdp answer is:

```
v=0
o=- 3917536185 3917536185 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 62599 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 0 8
c=IN IP6 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52
a=recvonly
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=mid:0
a=msid:4d904711-0eb0-4d3d-bb89-893f4278e1d5 575a987a-80a5-422a-8975-8f404438c6e3
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-mux
a=ssrc:2656472875 cname:e6892679-708a-446b-a54c-3dec1d3e20aa
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=candidate:db0577dc8a05b95fe58fbb6ae47f59e7 1 udp 2130706431 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52 62599 typ host
a=candidate:833b59f98895d8f38fc343316e354ecd 1 udp 2130706431 2a02:587:4b95:1600:31ba:5d7a:57f6:a649 62602 typ host
a=candidate:4073186272ad67170d6f5d116fc06478 1 udp 2130706431 2a02:587:4b95:1600:99ef:ddf0:c156:571b 62605 typ host
a=candidate:55d8d01ea385d5ccfaee2f754ecbdebb 1 udp 2130706431 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1 62608 typ host
a=candidate:1abd375dac51df537bc583f5e69d4abb 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.188 62611 typ host
a=candidate:fe9dccbe15d857e08670aa0a2f8e1054 1 udp 1694498815 2.86.153.254 62611 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.188 rport 62611
a=end-of-candidates
a=ice-ufrag:aAIK
a=ice-pwd:zko67gEs7Kju1LVy4Jz3Ed
a=fingerprint:sha-256 D2:01:77:EB:9E:1B:0A:B3:36:E7:2A:10:C8:39:FD:DA:AF:14:12:56:FE:41:BA:98:70:47:D0:F3:5D:BF:CE:7B
a=setup:active
m=video 62599 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 102 103 106 107
c=IN IP6 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52
a=recvonly
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=mid:1
a=msid:4d904711-0eb0-4d3d-bb89-893f4278e1d5 757a148d-9b8f-4e4d-9865-0abfe03d2c4d
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-mux
a=ssrc-group:FID 3099954396 1033628511
a=ssrc:3099954396 cname:e6892679-708a-446b-a54c-3dec1d3e20aa
a=ssrc:1033628511 cname:e6892679-708a-446b-a54c-3dec1d3e20aa
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:103 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:103 apt=102
a=rtpmap:106 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:106 nack
a=rtcp-fb:106 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:106 goog-remb
a=fmtp:106 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=106
a=candidate:db0577dc8a05b95fe58fbb6ae47f59e7 1 udp 2130706431 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52 62599 typ host
a=candidate:833b59f98895d8f38fc343316e354ecd 1 udp 2130706431 2a02:587:4b95:1600:31ba:5d7a:57f6:a649 62602 typ host
a=candidate:4073186272ad67170d6f5d116fc06478 1 udp 2130706431 2a02:587:4b95:1600:99ef:ddf0:c156:571b 62605 typ host
a=candidate:55d8d01ea385d5ccfaee2f754ecbdebb 1 udp 2130706431 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1 62608 typ host
a=candidate:1abd375dac51df537bc583f5e69d4abb 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.188 62611 typ host
a=candidate:fe9dccbe15d857e08670aa0a2f8e1054 1 udp 1694498815 2.86.153.254 62611 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.188 rport 62611
a=end-of-candidates
a=ice-ufrag:aAIK
a=ice-pwd:zko67gEs7Kju1LVy4Jz3Ed
a=fingerprint:sha-256 D2:01:77:EB:9E:1B:0A:B3:36:E7:2A:10:C8:39:FD:DA:AF:14:12:56:FE:41:BA:98:70:47:D0:F3:5D:BF:CE:7B
a=setup:active
m=application 62599 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP6 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52
a=mid:2
a=sctp-port:5000
a=max-message-size:65536
a=candidate:db0577dc8a05b95fe58fbb6ae47f59e7 1 udp 2130706431 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:1573:c49d:cf0c:5e52 62599 typ host
a=candidate:833b59f98895d8f38fc343316e354ecd 1 udp 2130706431 2a02:587:4b95:1600:31ba:5d7a:57f6:a649 62602 typ host
a=candidate:4073186272ad67170d6f5d116fc06478 1 udp 2130706431 2a02:587:4b95:1600:99ef:ddf0:c156:571b 62605 typ host
a=candidate:55d8d01ea385d5ccfaee2f754ecbdebb 1 udp 2130706431 2a02:587:4b9c:f200:d8ff:8893:bca:60a1 62608 typ host
a=candidate:1abd375dac51df537bc583f5e69d4abb 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.188 62611 typ host
a=candidate:fe9dccbe15d857e08670aa0a2f8e1054 1 udp 1694498815 2.86.153.254 62611 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.188 rport 62611
a=end-of-candidates
a=ice-ufrag:aAIK
a=ice-pwd:zko67gEs7Kju1LVy4Jz3Ed
a=fingerprint:sha-256 D2:01:77:EB:9E:1B:0A:B3:36:E7:2A:10:C8:39:FD:DA:AF:14:12:56:FE:41:BA:98:70:47:D0:F3:5D:BF:CE:7B
a=setup:active
```

I am visiting `http://127.0.0.1:8080` from the browser, and i press allow button for allowing camera and microphone access.
Also the camera led is on.